# Is there a shortcut in Elixir similar to Python's enumerate?

Tags: elixir

In Python:

```
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
```

It basically takes an iterable and adds the index of each item to the item itself.

Is there an equivalent in Elixir?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, a helpful person (OliverMT) in the Elixir IRC channel pointed me in the right direction:

```
iex> Enum.with_index [1,2,3]
[{1,0},{2,1},{3,2}]
```

Docs: [Enum.with_index/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#with_index/1)

**NB**: compared to the result from Python, the order of index/value is swapped.
e.g It is {value, index} and not (index, value) like in Python.

Comment: it's Enum.with_index/1 :-) the Enum module provides lots of good stuff to manipulate/transform collections.